# Tap Adapter on Windows 7

Tags: windows, python-2.7, wmi, tun

I'm trying to create tunnel program using python on windows. These are the steps um following: 
1 - I downloaded tun/tap device
2 - Using WMI to be able to change the ip address elements

I'm facing a problem now. Tun\tap shows "IPEnabled = False" when I change it using WMI. It doesn't change anything in the interface, even when giving ip, defaultgateway, subnet mask.
It does however change my wireless interface when I apply the same commands on it.

What is going wrong? Is this the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At last i will make this one using windows and then use tun tap with programming stuff, it can be done using C# to create the tun/tap too